# git clone produces different permissions on different servers

Tags: linux, git, unix, permissions

When doing a git clone git://github.com/blasto333/PHP-Point-Of-Sale.git on one server the files permissions are (I am showing one file but it is like this for all of them):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 chrism chrism   3297 Apr  1 19:12 index.php
```

On the second server it is:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 rrdiaper rrdiaper   3297 Apr  1 19:14 index.php
```

On a third server it is:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 cmuench  cmuench    3297 Sep 17  2010 index.php
```

The 2nd server is complaining because the file is group writable (php suExec). I know I can fix it with a chmod -R 644, but I would rather understand why permissions are different.

Comment: Check your umask? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: But when I upload files via ftp they get the correct permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your umask. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, how you can find it out, but I assume, that on the second server the repository is created with `--shared=group`. This will (as it suggests) make the repository shared with the group and so it sets the appropriate settings, that allows users in the same group to push to the repository.

Comment: It ended up being the umask issue.