# Git Cloned Directory vs User-Created Directory

Tags: linux, git, macos, github

I am observing a bit of a spooky behavior after I clone a web application repository from Github. When I run the git clone command on the Mac and clone the repository into my web root, I then try to go localhost/webproject to launch it. I get the following error in the browser:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Now, if I take an run the following command

> cp -r Github-Clone/ NewDirectory

and then go to localhost/NewDirectory,I get the same error.

However, if I first create a directory manually and then copy files into it, it is recognized and the application runs in the browser.

Why does this happen? Is this a Mac or Git issue? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you do an `ls -al` and see the user permissions? It is probably that Git creates files that the web server user or world can't see.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519864/git-clone-produces-different-permissions-on-different-servers